# Bad rendering fonts in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have this example: http://mbcapps.es/desarrollo/

On the left you can see a menu.
In this menu use the font Helvetica Neue.

In Internet Explorer 10 font rendering is correct
In Google chrome also
In Opera also
In Safari for PC and MAc, is correct.

The problem is firefox (21.0, I have not been able to test in other Firefox version)

In Firefox font rendering is LOUSY.
Why?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what it looks like for you in Firefox 21 and other browsers?  Looks fine for me in Firefox 21 on PC.

Comment: I see the exact same font on Chrome and Firefox (21.0). Maybe your browser cache being funny?

Comment: I don't see the menu looking bad in Firefox, but the heading text does. The reason is that Firefox is adding a fake bold as it is in a h1 element. Setting font-weight: normal; fixes it.